# Jar depends on Spring Framework, but which version to include?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a library that I built which uses the Spring Framework. It uses @RestController and uses `spring-boot-starter-test` package for testing.

The library is *meant* to run inside of Spring MVC (likely Spring Boot).

The easiest thing for me to do is to specify Spring Boot starter parent in my POM:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

However, I don't know if the project using my library will use Spring Boot 2.x or Spring Boot 1.x.

So, what do I do? Even if I remove the `parent` tag and start trying to fish for ALL the dependencies that I need to get my library to compile again, won't I have the same issue again, i.e., Spring Framework 4.x vs Spring Framework 5.x?

What can I do in my POM.xml to make sure that when I package my library as a jar, that the jar will be able to be used in a project that can use either Spring Framework 4 or 5 (and likewise Spring Boot 1.x or Spring Boot 2.x)?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the version as a variable like

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>${version.spring-boot}</version>
</parent>
```

so when they use your library they have to set this as a variable like,

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.spring-boot>1.5.9.RELEASE</version.spring-boot>
    <version.spring-cloud>Edgware.SR2</version.spring-cloud>
</properties>
```

Comment: You seemed to be not understood the usage of the sping-boot-stater-parent...cause the vesions of several components like Spring itself etc. are already defined their.. just use groupId/artifactId of the needed part...

Comment: @khmarbaise Can you elaborate on what you are suggesting? I actually tried to run my library in a Spring Boot app. My library specified spring-boot-starter-parent of 2.0 and the client module specified spring-boot-starter-parent of 1.5.8. Interestingly enough, things worked without an issue and the Spring Boot logo showed up as v1.5.8. I wonder if there is nothing more I need to do OR if I am going to stumble upon some issue in some scenario I am not exercising at the moment?

Comment: Ok, did some tests. Whichever is the driving app, i.e., the one that depends on my library, is the one dictating which version of Spring the WHOLE thing will be. Meaning, it does NOT include BOTH versions of Spring. Just the one version that the client module declares as the version for Spring Boot. Nice!